# How know if a submap has a key on Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have this values.yaml

```
microservices:
  - name: service-1
  - name: service-2
    ingress:
      enabled: false
```

I want to know if microservices.X.ingress.enabled exists.

This is because if don't exists I use a default value from another variable.

Now I use this:

```
{{ if and (hasKey . "ingress") (hasKey .ingress "enabled") }}
    {{ $ingress = .ingress.enabled }}
{{ else }}
    {{ $ingress = $.Values.common.ingress.enabled }}
{{ end }}
```

Is there a way to access it directly and don't have to use two conditions?

If I only use "(hasKey .ingress "enabled")" I get this error: **"at <.ingress>: wrong type for value; expected map[string]interface {}; got interface {}"** because service-1 don't have a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful trick with this sort of structure is to extract the structure one level at a time, defaulting to an empty dictionary if absent.

```
{{ $ingressSettings := .ingress | default dict }}
{{ ... $ingressSettings.enabled ... }}
```

For the particular construction you show here, you probably want to honor

```
common:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
microservices:
  - name: without-ingress
    enabled: false
```

The various helpers like [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) treat both `nil` and `false` as "not present", which means you can't really use that to test a value that could be absent, or could be present-but-false.  You need to do something longer-winded using `hasKey`.

Probably if I wanted to write this, I'd use `default dict` as shown above to get a value for the per-item `ingress` dictionary, but then use the Helm [`ternary`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary) function to have only a single assignment to the actual variable.  That leads to the (dense) construction

```
{{- $ing := .ingress | default dict }}
{{- $ingress := hasKey $ing "enabled" | ternary $ing.enabled $.Values.common.ingress.enabled }}
```

The `ternary` arguments are eagerly evaluated, but since `$ing` should always be a dictionary, at worst `$ing.enabled` will evaluate successfully to `nil`.